# how to run encrypted .pyd or .so python file

Tags: python, .so, pyd

I have compiled a python script file using easycython. using below syntax.
easycython encrypt.py

Above script created .pyd file "encryption.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
But when trying to execute file using python using below syntax

```
python encryption.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
```

I am getting below error.

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file encryption.cp38-win_amd64.pyd on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

if I tried to run the .py file it executed as expected. Can anyone help how to run .pyd in windows environment or .so in linux environment.

Comment: pyd files are typically library files and not directly runable (but rather you import from them) ... that said knowing python there probably is some trick to run it as a script (but thats not really the intent)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks for your reply and sharing inputs. have used import to get required details from pyd files.